# How to implement multiplicity of zero-or-one in one-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database, database-relations

Assume Teacher-Student common scenario with two limitations:

- All the teachers should have at least one student (You teach or you are fired!)
- All the students should have zero or one teacher (Students are free to chose a teacher!)

The hard part is how to make sure a teacher has at least one student.
Is it possible to implement this using relational databases and guaranty the multiplicities just by the relations and without using trigger, computed column, and other fancy stuffs ?
[image]

Comment: Can a teacher be a student?

Comment: who are the students with zero teachers?

Comment: @SamHolder This is just an example. Is it possible or not?

Comment: I don't see how through relationship only.  Even with the use of different tables; and especially in the case of the 2 tables listed in example.  A student would not be able to select a teacher not in the teacher table.  and they can't be in the teacher table without a student.  Sam's comment I believe was to illicit thought about the issue in that it can't be done because you can't have a teacher with zero students; they wouldn't exist. Thus you can't enforce it.

Comment: @xQbert I think IMHO the problem is not about the scenario, it is about nature of RDB.

Comment: which I'm saying can't be supported though relationships only within the database, some trigger, code etc would be needed to enforce this conecept.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it by declaring a foreign key constraint from your teacher to your student's teacher selection column.  I'm not sure if all SQL DBMSs will support a foreign key constraint referencing a non-prime (and even non-unique) column, but MySQL at least has no problem with it, as long as the appropriate indices exist.  However, to insert a teacher you need to temporarily disable foreign key constraints since MySQL doesn't support inserts into multiple tables with a single query.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE `teachers` (
  `tea_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tea_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tea_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `stu_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stu_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tea_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stu_id`),
  KEY `tea_id` (`tea_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tea_fk`
  FOREIGN KEY (`tea_id`) REFERENCES `teachers` (`tea_id`)
  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

ALTER TABLE `teachers`
ADD CONSTRAINT `stu_fk`
FOREIGN KEY (`tea_id`) REFERENCES `students` (`tea_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

INSERT INTO students (stu_name) VALUES ('John'), ('Jane');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
INSERT INTO teachers (tea_name) VALUES ('Jacob');
UPDATE students s JOIN teachers t
SET s.tea_id = t.tea_id
WHERE s.stu_name = 'John' AND t.tea_name = 'Jacob';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: FWIW, in response to your remark about other RDBMS, MS SQL Server only allows foreign-key references to Primary Keys or Secondary Keys (aka `UNIQUE` Keys). I believe when MySQL is used in "strict mode" it also won't allow FK constraints to reference non-key columns.